# How can I reset Vim back to a plain vanilla install?

Tags: vim, plugins, installation

I have mismatched plugin files floating around `~/.vim`; I am experiencing a corrupted behavior within vim itself, and both my `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` are filled with things I don't understand.

Examples: NERDTree plugin displays two identical file drawers on start, settings in `.vimrc` and `.gvimrc` aren't manifesting themselves.

Is there any way that I can completely "re-install" vim? Or, is there a way that I can get a new `.vim` folder, and start over form scratch? I want to learn vim, but it's hard with all these plugins installed. I just want to start with a plain vanilla installation.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: can't you just move or remove everything on `~/.vim` and ~/.vimrc?

Comment: If I just deleted everything in `~.vim`, would that break vim, or would it just reset itself? I have no idea, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Maybe this should be migrated to http://superuser.com/questions ? VIM-related questions always seem to have the possibility to be appropriate there as well as here...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To remove everything from your vim configuration remove the entire `.vim` folder as well as everything from your `.vimrc` file.  Keep the empty file in place though because without it vim will start in compatible mode by default and you almost certainly don't want that.

Note that there are system-wide files that are not stored in your home directory but if you haven't tweaked any of those then the above steps are all you need to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks- but what happens if I then want to install a plugin? Do I just create new directories in `~/.vim`?

Answer (score 44):

```
cd
mv .vimrc .vimrc-old
mv .vim .vim-old
touch .vimrc
mkdir .vim
```

Comment: and then `touch .vimrc; mkdir .vim`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old question but there is another useful command you can use `mv ~/.viminfo ~/.oldviminfo`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825195), I moved .vim and .vimrc. which resulted in the error below

> bash: /usr/bin/vim: No such file or directory

I'm not sure why I was facing the error above. When I moved only the .vimrc to .vimrc-bkp and created a new empty .vimrc, vim started working like a fresh install.