# How to restore vim to default setting

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi, vim-plugin

I messed up my vim settings, and now I wanna restore all the settings to default and delete all the plugins. I have no idea how to open vimrc, so if your answer need me to edit vimrc please include the tutorials of editing this file. 
Thanks very much!

Comment: You can edit your vimrc using vim the same way you edit any other files?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824942/how-can-i-reset-vim-back-to-a-plain-vanilla-install

Comment: Maybe uninstall & purge and install again?